# My Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I wrote simple program following example from a book.
It's supposed to draw dice with random number of dots but it doesn't work.
I found this problem is caused by simple "switch" instruction.

Thing is I also downloaded this program from author's page and it does work.
After slight adjustment in formatting my code is identical but it's still broken.

It would be nice if someone could tell me what if going on.

This is how my code looks now (and doesn't work):
http://pastebin.com/1HJwpxi8

This is author's:
http://faculty.purchase.edu/jeanine.meyer/html5/dice1.html

I found that if I copy/paste "switch" instruction from author's code then mine starts working properly.

Comment: Can we see your code and the authors code? Perhaps use pastebin.com and give us a link? thanks

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if you don't post your code? "I cooked a meal following the recipe in some cooking book. But it doesn't taste good. Why?"

Comment: We need some sort of code. You may want to check out JSFiddle

Comment: In what way does it not work? What error is it giving (check the console)?

Comment: I could have gone for downvote already if the user was not new...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
                case 5;
                 draw4();
                 draw1();
                 break;
                case 6;
                 draw4();
                 draw2mid();
                 break;
```

Cases in a switch statement are to be followed by a colon, not a semi-colon. Replace `case  5;` with `case 5:`, as well as `case 6;` with `case 6:`...

and your code will work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I should change resolution because I couldn't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

first thing I see is that you have two `<body>` tags.

Edit: Also to add to the other answers, you need to learn how to read the javascript inspector built into your browser. In Chrome, that's the first thing I checked and it said

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

with a line number. After clicking the line number, it pointed me to syntax errors

```
 -> case 5;
     draw4();
     draw1();
     break;
 -> case 6;
     draw4();
     draw2mid();
     break;
```

Comment: As I said earlier, I changed my code so it's the same as author's one.

Comment: The author's code is wrong. :)
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.purchase.edu%2Fjeanine.meyer%2Fhtml5%2Fdice1.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0